# Magento 2 how to get swatch name instead of image on hover in category page?

Tags: category, magento2.3, color-swatches

i changed that code -

from -

```
' option-tooltip-thumb="' + thumb + '"' +
' option-tooltip-value="' + value + '"' +
```

to -

```
' option-tooltip-thumb="' + label + '"' +
' option-tooltip-value="' + label + '"' +
```

but still i am getting image on hover instead of text(swatch name)

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: yes clear cache many times